# How to parse of file of urls into a Python list?

Tags: python, file

I'm very new to Python 3, and coding in general so please go easy on me.

I'd like to input a list of urls that are inside of a text file.
Example of the contents of my text file

```
http://www.sslproxies.org/
http://www.xroxy.com/proxy-type-Anonymous.html
https://kingproxies.com/
```

How can I mass import the list into a proxy scraper program my friend created?
This is what I have so far

```
scrape_list = list(set(open('URList.txt', 'rb').read().splitlines()))
for url in scrape_list:
          os.subprocess('hisprogram.exe --addurl ' + url)
```

But this doesn't seem to work, would love if someone can help explain it to me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: "_But this doesn't seem to work,_" is not enough, you should report in your question  all the error messages that were produced, if any, or clearly state that the program ended w/o explicit errors but not producing the expected results (in this case, which results?).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It can help to take the [tour] and visit the [help] with further questions. This question doesn't have enough context for us to know the problem- what were the results, and how did they compare to the expected results? Consider reading how to write a [mcve] to help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close to the solution.  Just use `split()` instead of `splitlines` and there is not need for the *list* and *set* calls:

```
>>> with open('URList.txt') as f:
        scrape_list = f.read().split()

>>> scrape_list
['http://www.sslproxies.org/', 'http://www.xroxy.com/proxy-type-Anonymous.html', 'https://kingproxies.com/']
```